# Is app release require to test IAP react native android

Tags: android, react-native, in-app-purchase

Is app release in the closed test environment required to test IAP, or can we test IAP in debug mode while the metro server is running, for android in react native?

Comment: [Reference](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test)